# C++ OpenCV mouseCallback on inheritance class

Tags: c++, opencv, inheritance, callback

Consider the `Base` class, and the two `Child` classes:

```
class Base
{
public:
    ~Base() = default;

    virtual void mouseCallback() = 0; // this is overriden by the Childs!

    void mouseCallback2() { std::cout << "mouseCallback2 OK" << std::endl; }//Not overriden
};

class Child1 : public Base
{
public:
    ~Child1() = default;

    void mouseCallback() override;
};

class Child2 : public Base
{
public:
    ~Child2() = default;

    void mouseCallback() override;
};
```

Where the implementation is:

```
void Child1::mouseCallback()
{
    std::cout << "Child 1 OK" << std::endl;
}

void Child2::mouseCallback()
{
    std::cout << "Child 2 OK" << std::endl;
}
```

I have my `CameraVision` class:

```
class CameraVision
{
public:
   // ...
   void init();
   static void callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata);
private:
   Base* mBase; // A pointer to the Base class!
}
```

Which contains the `init()` method as follows:

```
void CameraVision::init()
{
    mBase = new Child1();

    // Here I set the callback
    cv::setMouseCallback("Title", callback, &mBase);
}
```

So that when the mouse has an event I have this, the overriden method crashes my application.

```
void CameraVision::callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
    if (event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        Base* tof = static_cast<Base*>(userdata);

        tof->mouseCallback2(); // THIS WORKS!

        // But this is what I need
        tof->mouseCallback(); // ERROR!!!!!!
    }

}
```

Why I can't use the `mouseCallback()` using inheritance of `Child1`?

I'm getting an `error`:

```
Exception thrown at 0x000000013F391938 in Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x000000013F391938
```

I was expecting the `output`:

```
mouseCallback2 OK
Child 1 OK
```

Comment: mBase is Base*, then you don't need to use &, simply `cv::setMouseCallback("Title", callback, mBase);`

Comment: @Tony J you are God! Please use your comment to answer the question with the same info as your comment so I can close the thread:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mBase is type Base*, then you don't need to use &, simply 
`cv::setMouseCallback("Title", callback, mBase);`

&mBase will give you a pointer to a pointer, so your static_cast doesn't give you back the original mBase pointer, but its address. Not sure how the first callback worked, both should result in UB.